# Fan control on MSI laptop: no pwm-capable sensors?

Tags: 16.04, fan, temperature, msi

I'm trying to control the fan speed of my MSI GS60-2PC laptop on Ubuntu 16.04.

But `pwmconfig` reports that

```
There are no pwm-capable sensors modules installed
```

I'm pretty sure these fans can be controlled, because some utilies on Windows can control them.

#### What I've done

1. I've run `sensors-detect` (as root) like this:

   ```
    yes | sensors-detect
   ```

It seems to only detect "coretemp". [Here's the full result](http://pastebin.com/NuF9kxQC).

2. Then `pwmconfig` (as root):

   ```
   pwmconfig
   ```

And [I get the famous message](http://pastebin.com/UDr9GjcN) `There are no pwm-capable sensors modules installed`.

3. I've tried the following things, which didn't work:

   - Adding to grub (and then rebooting): `acpi_osi=Linux`
   - Adding to grub (and then rebooting): `acpi_osi=!Windows 2012`
   - Adding to grub (and then rebooting): `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

#### What I get when I run the `sensors` command

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp3:        +50.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

EDIT: [Here's the result of lspci.](http://pastebin.com/SnfHbq4n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to have some control of the fan in Windows with the "Fan Control Tools" from Pherein, using the included GS660 profile for my MSI GS60 6QC laptop. So I made a small python script that is the Linux equivalent of Pherein's "Fan Profile Applier.exe":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

EC_IO_FILE="/sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io"

if not os.path.exists(EC_IO_FILE):
        os.system("modprobe ec_sys write_support=1")

def ec_write(addr,value):
    with open(EC_IO_FILE,"rb") as f:
        f.seek(addr)
        old_value=ord(f.read(1))
    if (value != old_value):
        print("                %3d => %3d" % (old_value, value))
        with open(EC_IO_FILE,"wb") as f:
            f.seek(addr)
            f.write(bytearray([value]))
    else:
        print("                     = %3d" % value)

for line in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines():
    print(line.strip())
    if line.startswith(">WEC "):
        addr,value=line.split()[1:3]
        ec_write(int(addr,0), int(value,0))
```

Here is the input file I currently use as argument, it's the Quiet.rw file generated with Pherein's tool:

```
-Profile Name: Quiet
[Temperatures_1]
>WEC 0x6A 0x2f
>WEC 0x6B 0x35
>WEC 0x6C 0x43
>WEC 0x6D 0x50
>WEC 0x6E 0x5A
>WEC 0x6F 0x5F
>WEC 0x70 0x64
----
[FanSpeeds_1]
>WEC 0x72 0x00
>WEC 0x73 0x10
>WEC 0x74 0x3E
>WEC 0x75 0x45
>WEC 0x76 0x4C
>WEC 0x77 0x54
>WEC 0x78 0x5B
----
[Temperatures_2]
>WEC 0x82 0x37
>WEC 0x83 0x41
>WEC 0x84 0x4B
>WEC 0x85 0x55
>WEC 0x86 0x5A
>WEC 0x87 0x5D
>WEC 0x88 0x66
----
[FanSpeeds_2]
>WEC 0x8A 0x0
>WEC 0x8B 0x3B
>WEC 0x8C 0x46
>WEC 0x8D 0x54
>WEC 0x8E 0x5B
>WEC 0x8F 0x5B
>WEC 0x90 0x5B
----
>RwExit
```

With the latest EC Firmware there is actually no in between 0 RPM and 3000 RPM for fan speed.

Comment: Wow ! I've just tried it and the fan speed changed, even though it's not so quieter than before.  I'm very interested :-)
A few questions: the changes reset when the PC restarts, don't they?  
Does is take every sensor into account or just the CPU?

Comment: I've just found [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/msi-gs60-ghost-ghost-pro-thread.742589/page-133#post-9643753) a profile for the GS60 that seems to work better than the GX660's profile you provided! On my machine at least. Maybe you have a different firmware version that makes the GX660's profile work better? As far as I understand, the differences are the offsets: the profile I found start at 0x69, not 0x6A.

Answer (score 0):

This laptop uses the Intel HM87 chipset. The mobile version of this chipset does not include PWM hardware so the fans cannot be controlled by the operating system. If any fan control is possible it will be via the BIOS.

The owners manual for the MSI G60 states that some models of this laptop have a "cooler boost" button that controls the fan speed. It also shows that pressing Fn+F5 cycles the laptop through different power management modes.

Comment: Weird: MSI claims that [this software](https://forum-fr.msi.com/index.php?topic=4349.msg33256#new) is able to "control" the fans. How does it do if its impossible?   ... Maybe it flashes the EC firmware?

Comment: @Electronwill This not application software it is a feature of the BIOS. I have updated my answer.

Comment: By "cooler boost button", do you mean [this button](https://scontent-cdg2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/10478925_776893612374476_3228416580649571616_n.jpg?oh=b922824d02b2c5cb8fdc3136f3f4aabe&oe=57C68C70) ? It seems that I don't have such a cooler button on my GS60. This button is available on the GE60 and GE70.

Comment: Thats a pity. The manual for your laptop says its available on some models.

Comment: I wonder where you've found the manual. [The official one, on the MSI website](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GS60-2PC-Ghost.html#down-manual), doesn't mention any cooler button. [Nor does the quick guide](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GS60-2PC-Ghost.html#down-quickguide). Anyway, you're right about the chipset, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You are right. I was reading the manual for a GE60 2PE Apache Pro

Comment: Well, eventually, the fans can be controlled by a software.

Answer (score 0):

On my MSI GP62 with Linux installed, the cooler boost button makes the right side fan work, which is stopped otherwise, and boosts the speed of both fans.

[image]
[image]

Comment: good to know! but there's no such button on the GS60