# MSI GE60 0ND Fan issue

Tags: 16.04, python, fan

Recently I've switched to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 7 on my laptop (MSI GE60 0ND). In Windows I was using Pherein Fan Profiler but in Ubuntu I could not find an alternative.

In a similar topic a python script is shared but, since I am new to Ubuntu I could not make it run.

Can you suggest me an alternative for this fan issue or help me run this python script in the following topic?

- [Fan control on MSI laptop: no pwm-capable sensors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783069/fan-control-on-msi-laptop-no-pwm-capable-sensors)